# TypeError: Trying to increment a 0-dimensional subtensor with a 1-dimensional value

Tags: python, theano

I'm a new guy in python, I'm coding theano these days and suffered a problem that bothered me many days, my code is like follows:

```
import theano.tensor as T

def compute_distance(location, dis_matrix, string1, string2, len1, lent):
def assign_distance(a_location, dis_matrix, string1, string2, len1, len2):
    temp = T.switch(T.eq(string1[a_location[0]-1], string2[a_location[1]-1]), 0, 10)
    dis_matrix=T.inc_subtensor(dis_matrix[a_location[0], a_location[1]], temp)
return dis_matrix, temp

result, updates = theano.scan(fn=assign_distance,
                              outputs_info=[dis_matrix, None],
                              sequences=location,
                              non_sequences=[string1, string2, len1, len2])
return result[0][-1], result[1]
```

what I am trying to do is assigning value based on string1 and string2 to some cell in dis_matrix, I use a condition T.switch(T.eq(string1[a_location[0]-1], string2[a_location[1]-1]) to decide value of temp, so that I can put temp into dis_matrix, but when I ran this code, I got error:

> TypeError: Trying to increment a 0-dimensional subtensor with a 1-dimensional value.

It seems that `T.switch` returns not a scalar but a 1-dim vector to me, if I change `dis_matrix=T.inc_subtensor(dis_matrix[a_location[0], a_location[1]], temp)` to `dis_matrix=T.inc_subtensor(dis_matrix[a_location[0], a_location[1]], 0)`, this code works well, so I think it must be somewhere T.switch gets wrong.

Could any help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: That is not valid python code. It would be great if you could write it such that it is completely self-sufficient and runnable by pasting into an IPython console.

Comment: thank you for reminder, I have already fixed the problem, I got the dimension of string2 wrong, anyway, thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not verified this proposition by writing and running some code but the problem is probably that `string1[a_location[0]-1]` and/or `string2[a_location[1]-1]` are not scalars and are actually vectors (maybe vectors with only one entry). Consequently the results of `T.eq` and `T.switch` are also vectors (with the true/false scalar values in `T.switch` being broadcasted). If `temp` is a vector and `dis_matrix[a_location[0], a_location[1]]` is a scalar then `inc_subtensor` will probably yield the error you see.

Comment: thank you Renshaw! I have checked my code and found the problem is exactly what you said, I made a mistake and the dimension of string2 is not right. Now I correct it and it works well, at first, I thought maybe T.switch return a vector instead of 0 or 10.